# Google+ not showing posts on communities

Tags: google-plus

Basically on my screen, it only shows what I have posted publicly all the way when I first created my account and it does not show any posts from communities. It does show posts I put publicly (posts shared on profile), but not posts I put on communities. Other people on my profile can see the posts I put on communities, but I can't see them and I can only see the "Shared Publicly" posts.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: It should be showing them. Profile → View profile as: Yourself